# Can I assume that calling realloc with a smaller size will free the remainder?

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

Let’s consider this very short snippet of code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char* a = malloc(20000);
    char* b = realloc(a, 5);

    free(b);
    return 0;
}
```

After reading the man page for realloc, I was not entirely sure that the second line would cause the 19995 extra bytes to be freed. To quote the man page: `The realloc() function changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.`, but from that definition, can I be sure the rest will be freed?

I mean, the block pointed by `b` certainly contains 5 free bytes, so would it be enough for a lazy complying allocator to just not do anything for the realloc line?

Note: The allocator I use seems to free the 19 995 extra bytes, as shown by valgrind when commenting out the `free(b)` line :

```
==4457== HEAP SUMMARY:
==4457==     in use at exit: 5 bytes in 1 blocks
==4457==   total heap usage: 2 allocs, 1 frees, 20,005 bytes allocated
```

Comment: The header `<malloc.h>` is not defined by the Standard: prefer to use `<stdlib.h>`. Also casting the return value from `malloc` (or `realloc`) serves no useful purpose and may hide an error (*representation of `void*` and `int` being different*) the compiler would have caught otherwise.

Comment: ["The size of the memory block pointed to by the ptr parameter is changed to the size bytes, expanding or reducing the amount of memory available in the block."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/realloc/)

Comment: @pmg ok I did not know that.  I’ll change in my snippet

Comment: Note that Valgrind does not reflect the performance of your normal allocator because it actually replaces the allocator you usually use with one provided by Valgrind.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, guaranteed by the C Standard if the new object can be allocated.

> (C99, 7.20.3.4p2) "The realloc function deallocates the old object pointed to by ptr and returns a pointer to a new object that has the size specified by size."

Comment: [The C99 draft](http://people.freebsd.org/~green/c9x-draft.txt) never mentions anything against realloc doing nothing when the old size equals the new one. I guess all implementations violate it?

Comment: C99 7.20.3.4 §4: *The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may have the same value as a pointer to the old object)*

Answer (score 29):

Yes—if it succeeds.

Your code snippet shows a well-known, nefarious bug:

```
char* b = (char*) realloc(a, 5);
```

If this succeeds, the memory that was previously allocated to `a` will be freed, and `b` will point to 5 bytes of memory that may or may not overlap the original block.

*However*, if the call fails, `b` will be`null`, but `a` will still point to its original memory, which will still be valid.  In that case, you need to `free(a)` in order to release the memory.

It's even worse if you use the common (dangerous) idiom:

```
a = realloc(a, NEW_SIZE);     // Don't do this!
```

If the call to `realloc` fails, a will be `null` and its original memory will be orphaned, making it irretrievably lost until your program exits.

Comment: You are right. I had seen cppcheck complain about this. I guess this one is a killer for exam tests, but really, does this ever, ever happen?

Comment: @qdii: in the embedded world all bets are off; also, the os might enforce some limits, eg on virtual memory space via `ulimit`

Comment: Yes this really happens in the real world. Why do you think so much crappy software crashes when you run out of memory (on a system with no swap) rather than giving you a message that it can't perform the requested operation due to lack of memory?

Answer (score 4):

This depends on your libc implementation. All of the following is conformant behaviour:

- doing nothing, ie letting the data remain where it is and returning the old block, possibly re-using the now unused bytes for further allocations <del>(afaik such re-use is not common)</del>
- copying the data to a new block and releasing the old one back to the OS
- copying the data to a new block and retaining the old one for further allocations

It's also possible to

- return a null pointer if a new block can't be allocated

In this case, the old data will also remain where it is, which can lead to memory leaks, eg if the return value of `realloc()` overwrites the only copy of the pointer to that block.

A sensible libc implementation will use some heuristic to determine which solution is most efficient.

Also keep in mind that this description is at implementation level: Semantically, `realloc()` always frees the object as long as allocation doesn't fail.

Comment: Regarding "afaik such re-use is not common", I have never heard of a real-world implementation that leaves the old allocation in-place and does not free the tail for reuse. This would be pathologically bad, albeit legal, behavior.

Comment: Are there any standards that define this behavior, or is it really up to libc implementation?

Comment: @rr-: the C standard as well as POSIX leaves it up to the implementation; I'm unaware of any specification that does define the behaviour, but it might be documented in the libc manual

Answer (score 1):

It seems unlikely that 19995 bytes were freed.
What's more likely is that realloc replaced the 20000-byte block by another 5-byte block,
that is, the 20000-byte block was freed and a new 5-byte block was allocated.

Answer (score 1):

The realloc function has the following contract:

void* result = realloc(ptr, new_size)

- If result is NULL, then ptr is still valid and unchanged.
- If result is non-NULL, then ptr is now invalid (as if it had been freed) and must not ever be used again. result is now a pointer to exactly new_size bytes of data.

The precise details of what goes on under the hood are implementation-specific - for example result may be equal to ptr (but additional space beyond new_size must not be touched anymore) and realloc may call free, or may do its own internal free representation. The key thing is that as a developer you no longer have responsibility for ptr if realloc returns non-null, and you do still have responsibility for it if realloc returns NULL.

Comment: In addition, passing new_size = 0 is the same as free (ptr) and returns NULL. That would be a case where result == NULL and ptr is not valid anymore.