# How do I free certain rows and columns of a matrix

Tags: c, matrix, free, realloc

So I have a matrix which was created this way :

```
 int **mat(int nl, int nc) {
  int i;
  int **v = malloc(nl * sizeof(int *));

  for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
    v[i] = calloc(nc, sizeof(int));
  }
  return v;
}
```

Let's say after the input , it is :

```
0 1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
2 3 4 5 6 7
```

I would want to keep only the first 2 rows and first 3 columns , and free the memory of the other rows and columns , so it would look like :

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
```

How do I do that ?

Comment: There is no matrix (aka 2D array) in you code. `int **` is not a 2D array, cannot point to one or represent one. Why do you want to free the memory? Just don't use all space. There hardly is anything gained with partial freeing, you just frament memory space.

Comment: I see your point. But if you have big rows like 10000 elements and resize to, say 4000 elements, it could be interesting because you would have room for another "matrix" like this, and there would not be any memory copy in the `realloc` process. Memory is fragmented, but so are the matrixes. It depends on the difference of row sizes before/after resize.

Answer (score 2):

you would have to:

- free the full rows after the 2 first ones (and set `nl` to 2):

like this:

```
for (i = 2; i < nl; i++) {
    free(v[i]);
  }
nl = 2;
```

- perform a `realloc` of the remaining rows (set `nc` to 3 as well)
- check `realloc` return code. In the unlikely case it would return `NULL`, fallback to keeping your old array ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575122/can-i-assume-that-calling-realloc-with-a-smaller-size-will-free-the-remainder))

like this:

```
  nc = 3;
  for (i = 0; i < nl; i++) {
    int *new_v = realloc(v[i], nc*sizeof(int));
    if (new_v!=NULL)
    {
       v[i] = new_v;
    }
  }
```

Edit: if you didn't change `nc` and print the "old" values, it would appear to have done nothing because the old values could be still there (freeing does *not* mean resetting the memory), but you may access unallocated data now: performing another allocation can reuse the freed data and overwrite it.

Comment: I did exactly that , and after trying to print the matrix , they still didnt freed. Only thing that happened is the first 2 elements on the third rows are now 0 , so I guess thats the only thing that freed . everything is the same

Comment: Time to look at your print routine a bit more carefully.  Perhaps it is reading off the end of arrays and causing mayhem.

Comment: @Andrei: even unallocated, the data is still there until another allocation trashes them.